# Is there a Java library for all HTML tag names?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering if there exists any Java library that contains all HTML tags. I am writing selenium tests for fairly complex web sites using the Java binding, and often needing to find an element by tag name. I thought having a class with constants referring to each tag name would be nice.  Since there is a finite list of HTML tags, I'm thinking this must already exist. I could begin writing mine, of course, but why reinvent the wheel if there is one out there. I have checked the Selenium Java API documentation but can't find any. Any suggestions?

Comment: A list of tags is easy to find https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ and I think you can define your own tags so such a list doesn't cover the user defined tags

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. You **might** try your luck at [softwarereqs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) - but **first** study the corresponding help center to enable yourself to understand the policies of that community (instead of again dumping a question that violates the terms and conditions of that community). And consider deleting *this* question please! Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this. You are rarely going to locate an element by only the tag name so this won't be as useful as you think. Learn how to write CSS selectors efficiently and use those instead.

Comment: In java, use below Tag[] tags = HTML.getAllTags();

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not believe such a library is currently available.

Although there are a finite number of STANDARD tags in html, there is also the ability to have USER DEFINED tags. There are also different versions of HTML (current is HTML5) that support many different tags For example the  tag is no longer supported in HTML5, but does exist in older versions of HTML.  These two factors may make it increasingly difficult to create a definitive library of all tags.

The best option would probably be to create your own, personalized library for the project.